# How to prove that this specific matrix has the following form when raised to a certain power?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $A = \sum{_{k=1}^{n-1}} kE_{k,k+1} $ be an $n \times n$ matrix where $E_{i,i+1}$ has zeroes everywhere except the $i,i+1$:th component where it has a one.

For example, if A was $3 \times 3$ it would be

$A =  \begin{matrix}
0 & 1 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 2\\
0 & 0 & 0
\end{matrix}$

It is clear that $A$ is nilpotent of order $n$, however I claim that $A^{n-1}$ has one entry in the $1, n$:th entry that is n! and zeros everywhere else. How would I go about to show this?

The reason I ask is that I need this for an induction proof. Thanks

Comment: In your matrix, $A_{2,3} = 2$. Is that intentional, or should it be a one?

Comment: If you change the basis from the canonical $e_r$ ($r=0\dots n-1$)  to $f_r=\frac{1}{r!}e_r $ then you are looking at the standard (nilpotent) Jordan block $J_{n}(0)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $\;A=(a_{ij})\;$ , with $\;a_{ij}=0\;\;\forall\,i\neq i+1\;$, then

$$A^2=\left(\sum_{k=1}^n a_{ik}a_{kj}\right)\;,\;\;\text{where}\;\;a_{ik}a_{kj}=\begin{cases}0, &k\neq i+1\;\;or\;\;j\neq k+1\\{}\\
1,&k=i+1,\,j=k+1=i+2\end{cases}$$

Observe carefully the last line above...and there you go. Some small inductive argument and you shall be thru.